# Изменяется размер при компиляции приложения WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Суть такая, пишу программу по курсовой на ноуте. Постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что после компиляции приложения элементы управления уменьшаются в размере.
[image: как выглядит программа при разработке]

как выглядит программа при разработке выше.

Дале запускаю компиляцию и получается это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал исправлять и StackPanel'ю. Не помогает, также происходит уменьшение элемента

Размер приложения фиксированный, код ниже

```xml
<Window x:Class="Kursach.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kursach"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="RECOHALF | АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ" Height="550" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Border CornerRadius="20" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="C:\Users\andur\source\repos\Kursach\bin\Debug\fon.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="120" Height="40" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.488"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: Убери высоту и ширину, дай контейнеру за тебя настроить высоту и ширину...

Comment: 1. Размеры, не делайте их статичными. 2. Позиционирование, научитесь размещать объекты не при помощи отступов, а при помощи всяких панелей по типу `StackPanel` и др.. 3. `RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,0.488"` - это вообще что-то странное, зачем, не понятно... 4. Путь до изображения также статичен, на другом компьютере не откроется, да и вообще, использовать изображение, не лучший вариант, особенно в таком элементарном дизайне, как у вас.

Comment: Здесь чего-то не хватает, это не полная разметка, нет стилей и т.д. В показанной разметке причин для отображаемого на скриншоте поведения не вижу. Как воспроизвести то что вы показали на экране?

Comment: @aepot Все стили на картинке, которая идет фоном) Включая "поля" для ввода, поверх которых выводится `TextBox`. Тут типичная проблема позиционирования и установки размеров контролам.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я вот не вижу классических марджинов. Хотелось бы видеть источник косяка не на картинке, а в разметке, текстом.